# How do I make a CSS dropdown menu with my CSS?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, menu

I am having an issue with my code. I have a header (a simple, yet nice one) so I would not like to change my code a whole bunch to add a drop down menu. I do not use a list, as most people do for their drop down menu, and I would prefer not to use a list.

Here is my code:

```
<!-- Navigation Bar -->

<div class="navbar">
    <div class="button_l"><a href="Main_Page.html"> Home </a></div>
    <div class="button"><a href="About.html"> About </a></div>
    <div class="button"><a href="History.html"> History </a></div>
    <div class="button"><a href="Breakdown.html"> Breakdown </a></div>
    <div class="button_r"><a href="#"> Yeah </a></div>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS that goes with it:

```
.navbar {
width: 90%;
height: 30px;
font-family: 'Press Start 2P', cursive;
font-size: 15px;
line-height: 25px;
position: absolute;
border: 2px solid;
border-radius: 250px;
background: url("../images/navbar.png") repeat-x;
margin-left: 50px;
}

.button a {
float: left;
width: 20%;
height: 30px;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
}

.button_l a {
float: left;
width: 20%;
height: 30px;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
}

.button_r a {
float: left;
width: 20%;
height: 30px;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
}

.button a:hover {
float: left;
color: #fff;
width: 20%;
height: 30px;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
background: url("../images/navbar_roll.png") repeat-x;
}

.button_l a:hover {
float: left;
color: #fff;
width: 20%;
height: 30px;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
border-top-left-radius: 250px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 250px;
background: url("../images/navbar_roll.png") repeat-x;
}

.button_r a:hover {
float: left;
color: #fff;
width: 20%;
height: 30px;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
border-top-right-radius: 250px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 250px;
background: url("../images/navbar_roll.png") repeat-x;
}
```

I use button_l for the left button, button for the middle three buttons, and button_r for the right button. I would prefer for the "Breakdown" button be able to have a drop down menu, for perhaps two or three pages. How can I do this without making a ul and li tags?

Thanks

Also, no javascript please. Just simple and pure HTML and CSS.

Comment: Where is the supposed submenu...I can't see one in your HTML. http://jsfiddle.net/ryJT4/

Answer (score 0):

You could do this way

```
<div class="navbar">
    <div class="button button_l"><a href="Main_Page.html"> Home </a><div class="sub-menu">Menu here</div></div>
    <div class="button"><a href="About.html"> About </a></div>
    <div class="button"><a href="History.html"> History </a></div>
    <div class="button"><a href="Breakdown.html"> Breakdown </a></div>
    <div class="button button_r"><a href="#"> Yeah </a></div>
</div>
```

Add the following CSS

```
.button {
    position:relative; 
}
.sub-menu {
    position:absolute;
    top:100%;
    left:-10000px;
}
.button:hover .sub-menu {
    left:0;
}
```

Should look like this http://jsfiddle.net/ryJT4/1/

Comment: That works, but it only lets me do one drop down box... How would I do more than one, say two or three? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Semantically, it would be better to use a `nav` rather than a `div` with an unordered list for each item. You can then use the `li`'s hover to easily toggle the display of your subnav. Something like:

**Markup**

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Three</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Four</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Five</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

**Styles**

```
li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
ul ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 1em;
}
ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find a responsive, 2-level pure HTML/CSS dropdown here:

http://codepen.io/manik314/pen/BaqrI